# Django login page reloads and refreshes after entering username and password. Diagnosis says form is invalid but I don't know how?

Tags: django, django-3.0

It's a Django project. Upon entering the username and password, the login page refreshes and reloads instead of taking me to the homepage.html. When I ran a diagnostic in the view using print(form.is_valid()), it presented me with the base HTML code that makes up the built-in Django {{form}}, in the terminal. However, I'm unable to understand where exactly the fault lies.

1.The Login View

```
def authentication(request):
  print(request.method)
  if request.method=='POST':
     form=LoginForm(request.POST)
     print(form.errors)
     print(form)
     print(form.is_valid())
     if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        username=form.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password=form.cleaned_data.get('password')
        user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponse('Success')
     else:
        print('code failed')
  else:
    form=LoginForm()
  return render(request, 'TCloneTemplates/login.html', {'form':form})
```

2.Forms.py

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    username = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'hello'}))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': '', 'id': 'hi',}))

    def is_valid(self):
        form = super(LoginForm, self).is_valid()
        for f, error in self.errors.items():
            if f != '__all__':
                self.fields[f].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'error', 'value': strip_tags(error)})
        return form
```

3.Login.html

```html
<body>
    <div class="pic">
      <form method="POST">
        {% block content %}
          {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.non_field_errors }}
          {{form}}
          <button type="submit">Get Inside</button>
        {% endblock content %}
      </form>
    </div>  
  </body>
```

4.The url that takes me there

```
path('loginer/', views.authentication, name='loginer')
```

5. The diagnostic message in the terminal

```
POST

    <tr><th><label for="hello">Username:</label></th><td><input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="hello" maxlength="150" required></td></tr>
    <tr><th><label for="hi">Password:</label></th><td><input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="" id="hi" required></td></tr>

False

code failed
```

Comment: first remove the `is_valid()` method from your form and let us know if the problem is still occurring. Also tell us what is `AuthenticationForm` that you're inheriting from. And finally, `print(form.errors)` doesn't print anything?

Comment: When I remove is_valid() function from my form, it gives me the error "there is no valid() function present in the form". The AuthenticationForm function is an inbuilt Django function. print(form.errors) prints False. Nothing else.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever: "there is no valid() function present in the form" isn't a python error and does it say "valid()" or "is_valid()"? Anyway, you should be able to remove the `def is_valid()` method, since `AuthenticationForm` inherits from `Form` which has this method. Also `print(form.errors)` cannot print `False`. If there are no errors, it would output `{}` because `errors` is a dictionary.

Comment: So with the code you're showing here, it's not possible you get what you say. Please check that the code you're showing is exactly the same as the code you have in your project.

Comment: What I meant was that the error message goes something on those lines! Also, False was a response from print(form.is_valid()). I tried the code after removing the def is_valid() and it makes no difference. The result is the same; login page refreshing and reloading.

Comment: So what is `form.errors`? I ask you precise questions, I expect precise answers. Programming is precision work, debugging is too. You can't write on SO that the error is some string that can never be the actual error.

Comment: The way the `AuthenticationForm` works is that you initialize it with the request and the data: try `form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)`. see [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm).

Comment: We’re trying to help you debug an issue. So yes, copy & pasting errors is how debugging works on SO. Please do paste the entire terminal output if that helps. Anyway, the answer is given below now.

Comment: Cheerios dirky! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your form is obviously not valid (`form.is_valid()` is `False`) but has no errors, it means that your form is [unbound](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/api/#ref-forms-api-bound-unbound). You can check this by printing `form.is_bound` and you'll see it returns `False`.

That indicates that you didn't pass data to it. Strange, because you initialise it with `LoginForm(request.POST)`.

So the first thing to look at is the documentation or source code for `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm`, which you can read [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm):

> Takes **`request`** as its first positional argument, which is stored on the form instance for use by sub-classes.

This means the first positional argument is interpreted as `request` and you need to pass the posted data as `data` parameter:

```
form = LoginForm(request, data=request.POST)
```

This should now bind the form.

**Note**: It helps to make your diagnostic messages more clear, so that you can actually also spot empty strings: `print(f"errors: {form.errors}")` will at least show the "errors:" line, even if there are no errors. `print(f"is valid: {form.is_valid()}")` will let you know the `False` comes from this check, not something else.